# How to get Image `alt` value from Wordpress image attachment?

Tags: images

I am using a WCK plugin to Wordpress. In the php code to call the image source, I used `wp_get_attachment_image_src()` but it only gets the url of the image. I want to include the alt value of it. Please help. Thanks.

Below is my code.

```
<div class="authortest-cont">
                <h2><span>W</span>hat Our <small>Authors Say</small></h2>
                <?php
                $wck_custom = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'testimonialsbox', true);
                foreach($wck_custom as $wck_cstm) {

                    $author_name = $wck_cstm['author_name'];                            
                    $author_img = $wck_cstm['author_img'];
                    $author_testimonial = $wck_cstm['author_testimonial'];

                    if( is_numeric( $author_img ) ) {
                        $attach_author_img = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $author_img, 'full' );
                        $src_author_img = $attach_author_img[0];
                    }
                    else {
                        $src_author_img = $author_img;
                    }

                ?>


                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                    <?php echo $author_testimonial; ?>
                    <div class="author-det">
                        <img src="<?php echo $src_author_img; ?>" alt=""/>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <?php } ?>
            </div>
```

How `echo` alt value of that image?

Answer (score 3):

This looks like how you should use WCK:

```
<?php
foreach( get_cfc_meta( 'testimonialsbox' ) as $key => $value ){ ?>
    <?php $author_testimonial = $key['author_testimonial']; ?>
    <?php $photo_obj = get_cfc_field( 'testimonialsbox','photo', false, $key );  ?>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
        <?php echo $author_testimonial; ?>
        <div class="author-det">
            <img src="<?php echo $photo_obj['url'] ?>" alt="<?php echo $photo_obj['alt']; ?>"/>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: how to return alt value of that image attachment?

Comment: I add the get_post_meta function to my answer.  I think it is what you are looking for.

Comment: how to implement this to my code, above?

Answer (score 2):

`wp_get_attachment_image()` will generate a full image tag, including the alt attribute. If you need to put a custom class or attribute on the image (one reason you might only want the src), you can still do that with that function by using the 4th argument:

```
echo wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment_id, 'large', false, array( 'class' => 'my-custom-class' ) );
```

If you just want the alt text on its own, then given the ID of the attachment you can just use:

```
echo get_post_meta( $attachment_id, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true );
```

Comment: how to get the image of that attachment?

Comment: Is it automatically given?

Comment: In my first code snippet you'll get full `<img src=""` etc. HTML, so you'll get the image. If you're only using the second snippet, then you'd continue to use the `wp_get_attachment_image_src()` to get the URL.

Comment: I am using the `get_post_meta($post->ID, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true);` but it returns empty string

Comment: What is `$post`? That's going to be the post, not the image attachment. You need to give it the attachment ID. Same as you were giving to the `_src` version. And make sure you, you know, *have* alt text.

Comment: how to implement your code to my code above? please help, I can't get it.